# How to make grid spacing in draw.io a multiple of 50?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

In draw.io there are three minor grid lines between major grid lines:

[image: Here is screenshot showing how there are three minor grid lines between major grid lines]

If I draw a line between major grid points it will be 40 points long. I want to make it 50.

How can I make the major grids multiples of 50?

Answer (score 1):

go to Extras -> draw.io Configuration and enter this: 
{
"defaultEdgeLength":50
}

Answer (score -1):

I've had the same issue. I didn't really solve it, but what I did was setting the grid size to 25 instead of 10, so when I drew a line from one major grid line to the next it was 100pt, which kinda does the same thing. For me it worked.